# convert php curl api post to wp_remote_post()?

Tags: wordpress, rest, php-curl

I'm trying to convert the following curl to wp_remote_post():

```
$data = array(
    'token' => '123456ABCDE',
    'content' => 'record',
    'format' => 'json',
    'type' => 'flat',
    'csvDelimiter' => '',
    'rawOrLabel' => 'raw',
    'rawOrLabelHeaders' => 'raw',
    'exportCheckboxLabel' => 'false',
    'exportSurveyFields' => 'false',
    'exportDataAccessGroups' => 'false',
    'returnFormat' => 'json'
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://awebsite.com/api/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data, '', '&'));
$output = curl_exec($ch);
print $output;
curl_close($ch);
```

I've done several things, but the closest I've come to getting any sort of indication that wp_remote_post() is posting to the endpoint is:

```
add_action('the_content','api_call');

function api_call() {
    $url = 'https://awebsite.com/api/';
    $data = array(
        'token' => '123456ABCDE',
        'content' => 'record',
        'format' => 'json',
        'type' => 'flat',
        'csvDelimiter' => '',
        'rawOrLabel' => 'raw',
        'rawOrLabelHeaders' => 'raw',
        'exportCheckboxLabel' => 'false',
        'exportSurveyFields' => 'false',
        'exportDataAccessGroups' => 'false',
        'returnFormat' => 'json'
    );

    $requests_response = wp_remote_post($url, $data);
    return $requests_response;
};
```

The awebsite/api endpoint is saying "Failed API request (invalid token)". I've checked the same token in using python and its valid.

What am I doing wrong? Is my $data array not passing in the proper strings?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The $data keys => values should've been placed in the body array... like so:

```
$data = array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'headers' => array(),
        'body' => array(
            'token' => $token,
            'content' => 'project',
            'format' => 'json',
            'returnFormat' => 'json'

        ),
    );
```